# mod rewrite .htaccess expressionengine remove index.php and a specific subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expressionengine

Hate to ask this question, but I've been banging my head on the desk for a while and can't seem to get it.  I'm using ExpressionEngine, and I'm using mod_rewrite to remove index.php from all of my URLs.  That works fine.  Additionally, I want anything that is myurl.com/adwords/(anything) to be rewritten to myurl.com/(anything).  My regex and htaccess skillz are weak.  Here is what I have in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/adwords/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(ACT=.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

So I think I'm saying anything that ends in /adwords/(something), capture the something, and then append it at the end of index.php via $1.  I'm guessing this is simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule you are looking for as such is probably simply

```
RewriteRule ^adwords/(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

with no rewrite condition needed, but I wonder... do you really want to rewrite http://myurl.com/adwords/foo to http://myurl.com/index.php/foo, rather than to http://myurl.com/index.php?a=foo ?

If you also want to rewrite something like http://myurl.com/baa/adwords/foo to http://myurl.com/baa/index.php/foo, you have to omit the ^:

```
RewriteRule adwords/(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

BTW, you can test most of your rewrite rules here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Wow, that website is brilliant.  Solved my problems. Thanks a ton!